# Unable to figure out why AJAX is not triggering

Tags: php, ajax

I am spinning my wheels trying to figure out what is wrong in my code below. The function identified by ".func2" is triggering just fine and doing what it is supposed to do. However while the ".func1" function is being triggered all right (that window.alert 'I am here' is showing up), that AJAX call in ".func1"is not triggering. The "func2_email.php .... " is not being invoked.

Both of these functions are being invoked from the same PHP page.

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

     $(“.func1").on("click", function () {
        var fromEmail = $("#fromEmail").val();
        var toEmail = $("#to_Email").val();
        var transid = $("#refTransid").val();
        var repid = $("#initiatedby").val();
        var feed = $("#refFeed").val();
        var message = $("#to_message").val();
        var toName = $("#to_Name").val();
        var shareid = $("#shareid").val();

        //  window.alert(“I am here”);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: “func2_email.php?fromEmail=" + fromEmail + "&toEmail=" + toEmail + "&toName=" + toName + "&message=" + message + "&shareId=" + shareid + "&transid=" + transid + "&repid=" + repid + "&feed=" + feed,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#msg").html("<p class='successmsg'>" + toName + " has been notified");
            }               
        });
    });     

     $(“.func2").on("click", function () {

        var email = $(this).attr("email");
        var userid = $(this).attr("userid");
        var transid = $("#transid").val();
        var repid = $("#repid").val();
        var feed = $("#feed").val();

        var name = $(this).text();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: “func1_email.php?userid=" + userid + "&feed=" + feed + "&transid=" + transid + "&repid=" + repid + "&email=" + email,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                var scrollTop    = $(document).scrollTop();
                var top          = parseInt(scrollTop+260);
                $("#msg").html("<p class='successmsg'>" + name + " has been notified </p>");

            }
        });
    });         

});
</script>
```

Code for func2_email.php

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once("classes/autoload.php");
$db     = new Database();

//$fromEmail  = $_GET["fromEmail"];     // If client wants to use their internal user names
$fromEmail = "admin@mydomain.com";  //Central email address
$toEmail  = $_GET["toEmail"];
$toName  = $_GET["toName"];
$message = $_GET["message"];
$shareId = $_GET["shareId"];
$transid  = $_GET["transid"];
$repid  = $_GET["repid"];
$feed  = $_GET["feed"];

$host = $db->getDbHost();
$companyname = $db->getFieldValue("companyname", "apphost", $host, "appsettings");

$body   = "Dear ".$toName."," ."</br>".$message."</br>Please click on the link below to view the page”."displaytransaction.php?transid=".$transid."&id=".$shareId."&requestor=".$repid."&feed=".$feed."<br></br>Sincerely, </br>Customer Operations</br>".$companyname;



$mail = new PHPMailer(true);  // the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
try {
$mail->Host       = "smtp.mailgun.org"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Port       = 2020;                    /
$mail->Username   = “postmaster@mydomain.com"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "d2e3d568bb45ea649661d86d6a553cf";        // SMTP account password


$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->SetFrom($fromEmail);
$mail->Subject = "Requesting you to join a live video sharing session on     transaction #". $transid;
$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$mail->Send();

echo "Message Sent OK<p></p>\n";
} catch (phpmailerException $e) {
echo $e->errorMessage(); //Pretty error messages from PHPMailer
} catch (Exception $e) {
```

echo $e->getMessage(); //Boring error messages from anything else!
   }

?>

Comment: could you post your func2_email.php please

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser to make sure that it's indeed not triggered and it's not a case of something else going wrong.

Comment: Is this `“` a double quote character ?

Comment: @sr3z here's the code for func2_email.php

Comment: works for me after quote symbols replacement. The only question - is it intentionally ".func1" click calls func2_email and vice versa ? I mean I need to click func1 to call func2_email

Answer (score 0):

I've checked in my editor and tried to run this code in my local environment. Ajax call is made. Please try it, and than you can modify it according to your needs.

**html file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="func1 func2">test button</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $(".func1").on("click", function () {
            var fromEmail = 1;
            var toEmail = 2;
            var transid = 3;
            var repid = 4;
            var feed = 5;
            var message = 6;
            var toName = 7;
            var shareid = 8;


            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "func2_email.php?fromEmail=" + fromEmail + "&toEmail=" + toEmail + "&toName=" + toName + "&message=" + message + "&shareId=" + shareid + "&transid=" + transid + "&repid=" + repid + "&feed=" + feed,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#msg").html("<p class='successmsg'>" + toName + " has been notified");
                }
            });
        });

        $(".func2").on("click", function () {

            var email = 11;
            var userid = 12;
            var transid = 13;
            var repid = 14;
            var feed = 15;

            var name = 16;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: "func1_email.php?userid=" + userid + "&feed=" + feed + "&transid=" + transid + "&repid=" + repid + "&email=" + email,
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    var scrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
                    var top = parseInt(scrollTop + 260);
                    $("#msg").html("<p class='successmsg'>" + name + " has been notified </p>");

                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**func 1**

```
<?php

echo '<h1>FUNC 1</h1>';
```

**func 2**

```
<?php

echo '<h1>FUNC 2</h1>';
```

Comment: @Yonel, yes, those are simple " quotes (just the left of the ENTER key with a shift)

Comment: Nothing in Chrome or Safari